# Finding max out of pairs in a list

Tags: python, function, recursion

The problem I have to solve is to create a list of maxes for pairs in a larger list using recursion. For example, lets say the input is [ [2,4] , [6,7] , [9,9] , [2,1] ] i need to find the max of each individual pair so the desired output is [4,7,9,2]. I currently have

```
def twoMax(xlst):
    def mymax(x,y):
        if x > y:
            return x
        else:
            return y
    return_lst = []
    if xlst == []:
        return []
    else:
        for i in xlst:
            return_lst.append(mymax(i[0],i[1]))
            return twoMax(xlst[1:])
    return return_list
```

The function mymax is just used to find the max easier.
What i attempted to do was create a return_list where as it went through the recursion, it would add the maxes to the list. From what i understand is that in every stack through the recursion a separate `return_list` is being created.

EDIT: The problem with the current code is that it returns an empty list.
EDIT2: Typo in the example i desire the maxes not mins

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: Your example ([2,6,9,1]) returns the minimum value of each pair...

Comment: why recursion? You can achieve the maxes with `[max(item) for item in input_list]`

Comment: I assume it is a homework question.

Comment: @seymourgoestohollywood its a homework problem I need to use recursion and the function mymax for some reason

Comment: @JohanC, `empty` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up recursion and iteration.

`return twoMax(xlst[1:])` is redundant as it will always be executed, and pass the tail of the current list as it's argument, which will cause twoMax to be called again and again until xlst is empty, which will return [].

Remove this line and your code works.

I assume this is a homework problem (Since it's quite an overengineered function), so what you have now is an iterative algorithm. To make a recursive algorithm, you would need to do it a bit differently:

```
def twoMax(xlst, return_lst=[]):
    def mymax(x,y):
        if x > y:
            return x
        else:
            return y

    if xlst == []:
        return return_lst
    else:
        first_item = xlst[0]
        return_lst.append(mymax(first_item[0],first_item[1]))
    return twoMax(xlst[1:], return_lst)
```

This algorithm adds the max of the first_item of xlst to return_lst (an initially empty list), and then calls twoMax again on the tail of xlst, until xlst is empty, after which it returns the return_lst.

Answer (score 1):

```
def twoMax(xlst):
    if xlst == []:
        return []
    else:
        return [ max(xlst[0]) ] + twoMax(xlst[1:])
```